# How to hide password in HTTP request when using a servlet

Tags: java, servlets

This might be a duplicate, but I haven't found the answer that exactly resolves my problem... Sorry in advance if it's a duplicate.

I have an html form that takes a user name and password, and when I press Run request, it creates a post request to a servlet.
[HTML page screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlNP1.png)
The servlet itself doesn't need authentication. Instead, it uses the parameters to run another program in a process, which needs the user and password.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String user = request.getParameter("user")
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String command = "cmd /c someprogram --user=\"" + user + "\" --password=\"" + password + "\"";
    RunTime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    ...
}
```

But when I run this, the browser will show the http post request with the my password. Is there anyway that I can hide this?
[RequestScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQA7f.png)

Thanks alot!!!!

Comment: This is not a POST. It is a GET.

Comment: My bad... I following some Servlet tutorial and redirected doPost() to doGet()... (calling doGet() in doPost()). Beginner's mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Simply **hide** from browser address bar, **use POST** instead of GET.

==========

If you really **want to secure** your password,then **SSL is a must**.

POST is not **more** secure than GET as it’s also send unencrypted. 
SSL will cover the whole HTTP communication and **encrypt the HTTP dat**a send between the client and server.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML form element should have an attribute with method = post . (Formatting lacking as I'm on my phone)